# fckeditor characters encoding issue

Tags: codeigniter, encoding, utf-8, fckeditor

am using fckeditor inside codeigniter framework when i retrive data from data base it show an unreconized characters instead of special characters (french charachters like é è ç ..) ?
in data base data is converted to html entities, and i can show it without problem on the front pages, but in the backend i have a probleme with the editor!!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using htmlentities then use `html_entity_decode($string);` before you print it on the textarea.

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using tinymce editor because it is lightweight and provides much more options as compared to fckeditor.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/